# WPF States, what is the correct way of setting same property in multiple states

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to style a toggle button and I want the Foreground colour for the selected state and the MouseOver state to be white.

My style is as follows:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="border" >
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Cursor)" Storyboard.TargetName="MenuItemContainer">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Cursor>Hand</Cursor>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="menuText">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF19AA8D"/>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="menuText">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>


            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <StackPanel x:Name="MenuItemContainer" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="46" Margin="14,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="icon" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"  Foreground="#a7b1c2" FontSize="13" Text="&#xF009;" Margin="0,0,6,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#a7b1c2" FontSize="13" Text="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is working fine and for MouseOver and Selected states the foreground is set to white. However in Expression Blend Designer I see a warning message which says "To Avoid Unpredictable behaviour, you should not change an object-property in more than one state ..."

Should I just ignore this warning or is there a better way to implement what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should care about the warning. And in fact the style doesn't behave correctly. Do the following test:

1: set the button to checked -> the text turns to white -> ok

2: move the mouse away -> the text stays in white -> ok

3: move the mouse over the button -> the text stays in white -> ok

4: move the mouse away -> the text turns back to your non-checked default Color -> not ok

In other words you should not modify the same property of the same control from two different visual state groups. Just because the last change wins.

A solution in your case could be this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="border" >
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Cursor)" Storyboard.TargetName="MenuItemContainer">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Cursor>Hand</Cursor>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="menuTextMouseOver">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="iconMouseOver">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="menuText">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF19AA8D"/>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="icon">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="menuText">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>


            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <StackPanel x:Name="MenuItemContainer" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="46" Margin="14,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="iconMouseOver" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="13" Text="the icon" Margin="0,0,6,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuTextMouseOver" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="13" Text="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="icon" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#a7b1c2" FontSize="13" Text="the icon" Margin="0,0,6,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#a7b1c2" FontSize="13" Text="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!